# DHCP & macvlan: Only first virtual interface works with unicast DHCPREQUEST

Tags: dhcp, ips, unicast

**What I am trying to do?**

I'm trying to acquire 3 public IP addresses via DHCP on a single physical ISP upstream cable.

**What goes wrong?**

Renewals go kind of wrong. From interfaces, virtual0 works just fine when it tries to renew via unicast connection to DHCP server. virtual1 and virtual2 interfaces fail with unicast. They drop into fallback mode to use broadcasts and succeed with them, but spam the logs full of stuff which cannot be good. I'm running Debian 8 and isc-dhcp-client v. 4.3.1 .

I set up the interfaces on boot like this:

```
IF_VIRTUAL_BASE=eth0
IF_PUB0=virtual0
IF_PUB1=virtual1
IF_PUB2=virtual2
IF_LAN=eth2

ifconfig "$IF_VIRTUAL_BASE" up
ip link add link "$IF_VIRTUAL_BASE" address 00:90:0b:ff:10:5b "$IF_PUB0" type macvlan
ip link set "$IF_PUB0" up
ip link add link "$IF_VIRTUAL_BASE" address 00:90:0b:ff:11:5b "$IF_PUB1" type macvlan
ip link set "$IF_PUB1" up
ip link add link "$IF_VIRTUAL_BASE" address 00:90:0b:ff:12:5b "$IF_PUB2" type macvlan
ip link set "$IF_PUB2" up

# Enable forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

I also do `unset new_routers` when completing dhcprequest for virtual1 and virtual2.

And guess what, this monstrosity kind of works:

```
Jul 11 20:45:43 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:43 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:43 gw ifup[582]: DHCPREQUEST on virtual0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:43 gw ifup[592]: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:43 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:43 gw ifup[634]: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:46 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:46 gw ifup[592]: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:46 gw dhclient: DHCPACK from 88.113.75.2
Jul 11 20:45:46 gw ifup[592]: DHCPACK from 88.113.75.2
Jul 11 20:45:46 gw logger: virtual1 (REBOOT): IP:  -> 88.113.75.59; GW:  -> 88.113.75.1

Jul 11 20:45:47 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:47 gw ifup[582]: DHCPREQUEST on virtual0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:47 gw dhclient: DHCPACK from 88.113.75.2
Jul 11 20:45:47 gw ifup[582]: DHCPACK from 88.113.75.2
Jul 11 20:45:47 gw logger: virtual0 (REBOOT): IP:  -> 88.113.75.65; GW:  -> 88.113.75.1

Jul 11 20:45:50 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:50 gw ifup[634]: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 20:45:50 gw dhclient: DHCPACK from 88.113.75.2
Jul 11 20:45:50 gw ifup[634]: DHCPACK from 88.113.75.2
Jul 11 20:45:50 gw logger: virtual2 (REBOOT): IP:  -> 88.113.75.61; GW:  -> 88.113.75.1
```

So they worked, right? And they are broadcast requests. Ok, fast forward an hour or so we gets looots of this:

```
Jul 11 21:45:09 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:45:11 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:45:22 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:45:25 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:45:32 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:45:43 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:45:46 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:45:56 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:46:05 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:46:11 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:46:21 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:46:30 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:46:33 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:46:42 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:46:47 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:47:00 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:47:01 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 21:47:09 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
```

The virtual1 and virtual2 interfaces desperately try to renew their IPs via unicast connection to previous DHCP server 195.74.6.55 . They fail for the unicast. But something funny happens next, in the end they switch to broadcast as fallback and succeed!

```
Jul 11 22:30:41 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 22:30:47 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 22:30:52 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 22:30:52 gw dhclient: DHCPACK from 88.113.75.2
Jul 11 22:30:52 gw logger: virtual1 (RENEW): IP: 88.113.75.59 -> 88.113.75.59; GW: 88.113.75.1 -> 88.113.75.1

Jul 11 22:30:58 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul 11 22:30:58 gw dhclient: DHCPACK from 88.113.75.2
Jul 11 22:30:59 gw logger: virtual2 (RENEW): IP: 88.113.75.61 -> 88.113.75.61; GW: 88.113.75.1 -> 88.113.75.1
```

Observe the virtual0 interface:

```
Jul 11 22:38:17 gw dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on virtual0 to 195.74.6.55 port 67
Jul 11 22:38:18 gw dhclient: DHCPACK from 195.74.6.55
Jul 11 22:38:18 gw logger: virtual0 (RENEW): IP: 88.113.75.65 -> 88.113.75.65; GW: 88.113.75.1 -> 88.113.75.1
```

Conclusion is that for virtual0 interface, unicast (dhclient) DHCP requests work and for virtual1 and virtual2 only broadcast DHCP renewals work. So, it must be a routing problem, right? Here is what ip route shows after a typical boot:

```
root@gw:~# ip route
default via 88.113.75.1 dev virtual0
88.113.75.0/24 dev virtual0  proto kernel  scope link  src 88.113.75.65
88.113.75.0/24 dev virtual1  proto kernel  scope link  src 88.113.75.59
88.113.75.0/24 dev virtual2  proto kernel  scope link  src 88.113.75.61
172.16.8.0/28 via 172.16.8.2 dev tun0 # For openvpn
172.16.8.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.8.254 # For LAN
172.16.8.2 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.8.1 #For openvpn
```

How do I make the dhclients on macvlan-based interfaces virtual1 and virtual2 route their unicast renewal requests correctly and receive the responses appropriately?

I have done tons of Google searches, tried to flip-flop many settings, including firewall policies, policy-based routings, eth0 promisc mode and sysctl variables, stripping down the generic networking setup etc. I'm currently doing strace on dhclient. One combination of these settings must work. If more information is needed, I'm more than happy to provide.

**EDIT1**: dhclient strace became ready.

This happens in the very beginning:

```
bind(5, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x7669, if1635087474, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(0)={12652, }, 16) = 0
bind(6, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(68), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
sendto(5, "......", 342, 0, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x7669, if1635087474, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(0)={12652, }, 18) = 342
```

The "sendto(5" was, to my understanding, the first successful broadcast-based dhclient send.

Then, later the first failing unicast send:

```
sendto(6, "......", 300, 0, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(67), sin_addr=inet_addr("195.74.6.55")}, 16) = 300
```

And the next successful broadcast send:

```
sendto(5, "......", 342, 0, {sa_family=AF_PACKET, proto=0x7669, if1635087474, pkttype=PACKET_HOST, addr(0)={12652, }, 18) = 342
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it! In a bit of on unorthodox way, but still.

So what did I do? **I merely uninstalled isc-dhcp-client 4.3.1 and installed dhcpcd 6.0.5 (by Roy Marples, debian package name dhcpcd5).** That's it.

I rebooted machine at about 23:00 and checked that all interfaces were good, then set tcpdump running. At around 00:02 one of the DHCP timers expire and all 3 interfaces neatly get their IP addresses, no questions asked:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGQpq.png

Basically I did not need to change anything in /etc/dhcpcd.conf . It seems dhcpcd is built in a smarter way than dhclient. At least on my scenario.

(Sidenote: I must say it was quite easy to migrate from isc-dhcp-client to dhcpcd. Debian 8 had built-in support; it seems if you install dhcpcd5 and remove isc-dhcp-client and reboot, the system picks up the new client automatically. About scripts, it seems there is no script directory for dhcpcd, but single file for all enter hooks and single file for all exit hooks. Files were named: /etc/dhcpcd.enter-hook and /etc/dhcpcd.exit-hook . If you place your dhclient hook scripts into these files, they work without modifications. I'm impressed!)